# Xamarin Form 4 Shell

Tags: xamarin.forms

I start an new projet with the new Shell from Xamarin Form 4. I try to found a way to control the appearance when a `FlyoutItem` is disable. On the style with the sample, the BaseStyle control the apparence of the Shell himself (title bar tab bar, ...) But the `Shell.disableColor` is for the shell himself not the `flyoutItem` text. Any idea?

```
    <Shell.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#2196F3</Color>
                <Style x:Key="BaseStyle" TargetType="Element">
                    <Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
                    <Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                    <Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF" />
                    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
                    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95FFFFFF"/>
                    <Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="White"/> 
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="FAIcon" TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource FARegular}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource BigSize}"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#FF000000"/>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="ItemText" TargetType="Label">
                    <Setter Property="VerticalTextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource SourceSansProRegular}"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource BigSize}"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="#FF000000"/>
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Shell.Resources>

        <Shell.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="45"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.2*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.8*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Margin="15,0,0,0" Text="{Binding FlyoutIcon}" Style="{StaticResource FAIcon}" />
                    <Label Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{Binding Title}"
                           Style="{StaticResource ItemText}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Shell.ItemTemplate>
        
        <Shell.FlyoutHeader>
            <Grid HeightRequest="180" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource DarkGreyColor}">
                <Image Source="KelvinSplash1.png"
                       Aspect="AspectFill"
                       HeightRequest="180"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                <Label Text="Kelvin Mobile"
                       TextColor="White"
                       FontSize="32"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
        </Shell.FlyoutHeader>

        <FlyoutItem Icon="&#xf015;"
                    Title="Accueil">
            <ShellContent Route="Home"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:HomePage}" />
        </FlyoutItem>
        <FlyoutItem Icon="&#xf3b3;"
                    Title="Division: Solmec" IsEnabled="false">
        </FlyoutItem>
        <FlyoutItem Icon="&#xf732;"
                    Title="Fonctions">
        </FlyoutItem>
        <FlyoutItem Icon="&#xf05a;"
                    Title="À Propos"
                    IsEnabled="False">
            <ShellContent Route="About"  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:AboutPage}" />
        </FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: do you mean you want change the flyoutitem appearance when its `IsEnable = "False" `?

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: what effect do you want? couldn't you just define style for the disable FlyoutItem ? or you don't know the attribute you want to set ?

Comment: Just need to grey outthe Text Color when the FlyoutItem is disable. But I can't found where to style that? In the documentation, the DataTemplate do not provide the IsEnable for binding, only Title and FlyoutIcon.

Comment: hava you try to  set TabBarDisabledColor ?